# How to handle parse Push Response

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification

I have implemented `push` notification using `parse`.I am using this code to send Notification:

```
 PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"deviceType" equalTo:@"ios"];

// Send push notification to query
[PFPush sendPushMessageToQueryInBackground:pushQuery
                               withMessage:@"Hello World!"];
```

In my `AppDelegate.m` i have

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

As it is parse default method to handle PUSH. But i want to different things based on different message received.

How can extract the message from the `UserInfo` dictionary.?

Comment: There are many ways you can handle a push notification. You should read the Apple documentation on the subject, everything is explained : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

```
PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
//Send push to a particular user, granted you saved that with their installation
//Or customize your query anyway you want
[pushQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:_user];

NSMutableDictionary *pushDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
pushDictionary[@"type"]=@"message";
pushDictionary[@"alert"]=@"YOUR MESSAGE";
//You can use anything here... pushDictionary[@"a"]=@"b" etc...

[PFPush sendPushDataToQueryInBackground:pushQuery withData:pushDictionary];
```

The above code sends your push

Now in your AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
NSLog(@"userInfo: %@",userInfo);

    if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"message"]) {
        //You received a push of type "message", do whatever...
    }
    else{
        //Push is something else...
    }

}
```